# Button is not triggering raspberry pi 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a code for raspberry pi which should work when a push button pressed it should trigger an API request to the server, and start recording the event and replaying it on screen.

When I press the button nothing happens, is something wrong with my code?

I double checked the pin I'm using and the network connection but nothing seems to work whatsoever.

Here is the code I'm using as is without any change:

```
const { io } = require('socket.io-client');
const { Gpio } = require('onoff'); //include onoff to interact with the GPIO

const CAGE_ID = '642gghb533cb8d00784dbd8e';
const CLOUD_SERVER_URL = 'http://192.168.100.247:7890';
const BUTTON_PINS = [16, 17];

// const wifi = new WiFi();

let socket;
let recordingTimer;
let startRecordingTime;
let currentStreamId;

const stopRecording = () => {
  if (recordingTimer) {
    clearTimeout(recordingTimer);
    recordingTimer = null;
  }
  socket.emit('streamControllerFinished');
};

const startRecording = (numberOfMinutes, streamId) => {
  if (recordingTimer) {
    stopRecording();
  }
  startRecordingTime = Date.now();
  currentStreamId = streamId;
  recordingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    stopRecording();
  }, numberOfMinutes * 60000);
};

const socketConnect = () => {
  socket = io(CLOUD_SERVER_URL, { transports: ['websocket'] });

  socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
    console.log('connect_error', error);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    console.log('disconnect reason', reason);
  });

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connect');
    socket.emit('register', {
      clientType: 'cage_stream_controller',
      cageId: CAGE_ID,
    });
  });

  socket.on('cageStreamStartRecording', (data) => {
    console.log('connect');
    startRecording(data.numberOfMinutes, data.streamId);
  });

};

for (let i = 0; i < BUTTON_PINS.length; i++) {
  const buttonPin = BUTTON_PINS[i];
  const pushButton = new Gpio(buttonPin, 'in', 'both'); //use GPIO pin 17 as input, and 'both' button presses, and releases should be handled

  pushButton.watch(function (err, value) { //Watch for hardware interrupts on pushButton GPIO, specify callback function
    if (err) { //if an error
      console.error('There was an error', err); //output error message to console
      return;
    }
    if (value && currentStreamId) {
      socket.emit('streamControllerReplay', {
        cageId: CAGE_ID,
      });
    }
  });
}

socketConnect();

console.log('hello');
```

Feel free to request any more info.